# Why Hibernate Search indexing not working properly

Tags: spring, indexing, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I've integrated Hibernate Search to my backend for Full Text Search,

The application works fine, I added some info to my database(see the screenshots) but when I search for a word sometimes (word="1") I only get one result instead of multiple results, sometimes(for an other word "ex: maroc") I don't get anything. I think it's an indexing problem not a query problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my Entity code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.*;

import javax.persistence.*;;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name="client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="fullname")
    @Field(termVector = TermVector.YES,analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class))
    String fullName;

    @Column(name="adress")
    @Field
    String adress;
```

This is my SearchService code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class SearchService {


    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Autowired
    public SearchService( EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        super();
        this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void initializeHibernateSearch() {
        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Client> clientSearch(String searchTerm) {

        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Client.class).get();
        Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("id","adress","fullName")
                .matching(searchTerm).createQuery();

        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Client.class);

        // execute search

        List<Client> clientList = null;
        try {
            clientList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        }

        return clientList;
    }
```

This is my HibernateSearchConfiguration code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class HibernateSearchConfiguration {

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateSearchConfiguration(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    SearchService hibernateSearchService() {
        SearchService hibernateSearchService = new SearchService(this.entityManagerFactory);
        hibernateSearchService.initializeHibernateSearch();
        return hibernateSearchService;
    }
}
```

that's the error in the terminal btw:

```
2020-05-05 13:21:11,084 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.doWork(LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.WorkspaceHolder.applyStreamWork(WorkspaceHolder.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.performStreamOperation(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationExecutorSelector$AddSelectionExecutor.performStreamOperation(StreamingOperationExecutorSelector.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.executeWork(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.dispatch(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.batch.DefaultBatchBackend.enqueueAsyncWork(DefaultBatchBackend.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.index(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.indexAllQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2020-05-05 13:21:11,084 ERROR org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer : HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
2020-05-05 13:21:11,085 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.doWork(LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.WorkspaceHolder.applyStreamWork(WorkspaceHolder.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.performStreamOperation(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationExecutorSelector$AddSelectionExecutor.performStreamOperation(StreamingOperationExecutorSelector.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.executeWork(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.dispatch(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.batch.DefaultBatchBackend.enqueueAsyncWork(DefaultBatchBackend.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.index(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.indexAllQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2020-05-05 13:21:11,085 ERROR org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer : HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
2020-05-05 13:21:11,087 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.doWork(LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.WorkspaceHolder.applyStreamWork(WorkspaceHolder.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.performStreamOperation(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationExecutorSelector$AddSelectionExecutor.performStreamOperation(StreamingOperationExecutorSelector.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.executeWork(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.dispatch(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.batch.DefaultBatchBackend.enqueueAsyncWork(DefaultBatchBackend.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.index(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.indexAllQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2020-05-05 13:21:11,087 ERROR org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer : HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
2020-05-05 13:21:11,088 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.doWork(LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.WorkspaceHolder.applyStreamWork(WorkspaceHolder.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.performStreamOperation(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationExecutorSelector$AddSelectionExecutor.performStreamOperation(StreamingOperationExecutorSelector.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.executeWork(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.dispatch(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.batch.DefaultBatchBackend.enqueueAsyncWork(DefaultBatchBackend.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.index(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.indexAllQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2020-05-05 13:21:11,088 ERROR org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer : HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
2020-05-05 13:21:11,090 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.doWork(LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.WorkspaceHolder.applyStreamWork(WorkspaceHolder.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.performStreamOperation(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationExecutorSelector$AddSelectionExecutor.performStreamOperation(StreamingOperationExecutorSelector.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.executeWork(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.StreamingOperationDispatcher.dispatch(StreamingOperationDispatcher.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.batch.DefaultBatchBackend.enqueueAsyncWork(DefaultBatchBackend.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.index(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.indexAllQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2020-05-05 13:21:11,090 ERROR org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer : HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
2020-05-05 13:21:11,092 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.doWork(LuceneBackendTaskStreamer.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.WorkspaceHolder.applyStreamWork(WorkspaceHolder.java:75)
```

.....etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the stacktrace changes everything. The problem is not in your mapping.

See this:

```
2020-05-05 13:21:11,084 ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler : HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000117: IOException on the IndexWriter
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\ggg\jpa\indexpath\com.skylark.training.jpa.model.Client\write.lock
```

Hibernate Search failed to obtain a lock to the index writer. This can happen in two cases:

1. Your application was stopped (very) brutally and didn't release the lock. In this case, the easiest solution is to delete everything and reindex, because it's likely you lost some data when the application was stopped brutally.
2. You're attempting to use the same index from two separate instances of your applications. If you really need to do this, you should consider relying on Elasticsearch instead of a local Lucene index; see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_elasticsearch).

Comment: thank you for your help. can you please tell me what do you mean by deleting everything and reindexing and how to reIndex?

Comment: again when i restart my computer the writer problem desappear but still returns empty list, with debugger (in SearchService) at the LuceneQuerry"qb" variable it throws the exception : 
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.PropertyMetadata.toString()

Comment: i've restarted the hole think and its working now so i was in the first case thank u so much

Comment: @yrodiere Let's say in Case 2, that I have an Application 1 that only needs to read the index, and that another Application 2 writes and reads that same index.

Why does the reading Application 1 need to bother about the lock?
And was that any different in Hibernate 5 vs. Hibernate 7?

Comment: @f1v3 That could work in theory, but that's untested and hence unsupported. We'd certainly accept a pull request to add a read-only mode to the Lucene backend in Hibernate Search 7 though. Though I have no idea about performance, since I imagine you'd rely on a network share. And yes, Hibernate Search 5 was different since 5 attempted to solve the problem of distributed indexing, which we gave up on in favor of letting Elasticsearch/OpenSearch do it much better than we ever could (and without the many bugs).

Comment: @yrodiere Tanks for the quick reply and for the Information!
Can I read somewhere in the docs about the decision you mentioned, to drop the "distributed indexing" in Hibernate 7?

Comment: @f1v3 That would be the 6.0 migration guide: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#search-5-backends. And to clarify, distributed indexing is still there (and in fact [even better](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-examples-outbox-polling-elasticsearch)); it's just that it's expected to rely on Elasticsearch/OpenSearch, not directly on Lucene.

Comment: @yrodiere Thanks a lot for all the Information. Of course I read the Docs, but I seem to have skipped some of it :)
The Problem is, that my Company only planned for an Lucene Library Update, not for the change to Elasticsearch Backend... This would be a hard one to sell.
Thanks again!

Comment: @f1v3 Sure. As I mentioned, If you were just using Hibernate Search with one writing node, and one or more read-only nodes relying on a network share, that would probably only require adding a read-only configuration flag to Hibernate Search. And, come to think of it, you might even be able to handle multiple nodes writing to the database, as long as you configure outbox-polling and [disable event processors on all nodes but one](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#coordination-outbox-polling-event-processor-basics).

Answer (score 0):

You really should use the same analyzer in all text fields. If you don't specify an analyzer, the default one will be used, which may cause the problem you're experiencing.

```
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="fullname")
    @Field(termVector = TermVector.YES,analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class))
    String fullName;

    @Column(name="adress")
    @Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class))
    String adress;
```

Comment: same problem!
when i turned off my computer and start it again it worked without any changes and today it's not working again i don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

As yrodiere mentioned, working with the same index is not possible. A better solution would be to utilize ElasticSearch.

In Hibernate Search versions prior to 6, you can establish a master-slave relationship between different applications that share the same indexes.
[JSM Master-slave](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_search_reference.pdf)

Alternatively, as a workaround, you could consider deleting the write.lock file inside the index folder. Please note that this is a more forceful approach and may have unintended consequences.

I hope this information is helpful to you.